# What do you call the hooked tip of a kanji stroke?

Tags: kanji, handwriting, calligraphy, stroke-type

When writing a kanji, some downstrokes have a clean end (such as in 木) while others end with a little hook (e.g. the center stroke of 小).

What are the names of such stroke tips?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

「はね」is what I always hear it referred to as.
A web search finds lots of sources to back this up:
http://www.bunkei.co.jp/bunkei-app/soragaki/common/images/function.jpg
http://www.y-adagio.com/public/standards/tr_fnttrm/fig7_7.gif
http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AD%86%E7%94%BB
etc

Comment: When talking about kanji in English, I was taught they were called _jumps_.  Along with _stops_ (とめ) and _sweeps_ (はらい), they make up the three ways a line can terminate while writing Japanese characters.